# Ruby YAML array

Tags: arrays, ruby, yaml

I'm using the following resource from elasticsearch:

```
elasticsearch_configure 'elasticsearch' do
    configuration ({
        'path.repo' => ["/backups/s3_currently_dev", "/backups/s3_currently", "/backups/s3_daily", "/backups/s3_weekly", "/backups/s3_monthly"]
    })
end
```

I need exactly the following output:

```
path.repo: ["/backups/s3_currently_dev", "/backups/s3_currently", "/backups/s3_daily", "/backups/s3_weekly", "/backups/s3_monthly"]
```

But I obtain the following one:

```
path.repo:
- "/backups/s3_currently_dev"
- "/backups/s3_currently"
- "/backups/s3_daily"
- "/backups/s3_weekly"
- "/backups/s3_monthly"
```

This doesn't seem to work. How I can obtain the desired output?

Reproduce:

```
1- Install Chef.
2- Create a cookbook.
3- Use elasticsearch community cookbook to install elasticsearch and configure with the resource shown.
4- Use kitchen or vagrant to create.
```

Comment: Are you saying calling `path.repo` is giving you a YAML-like result? Maybe try writing steps to reproduce.

Comment: Yes. How I can change that YAML result into the output that I want? I've edited with steps to reproduce.

Comment: What do you get if you do `path.repo.class`?

Comment: path.repo isn't a class, it's just an string declaration.

Comment: Everything in Ruby is an object. `Object#class` tells you what the class of the object is. So do `path.repo.class` and tell me what it says.

Comment: My bad, it seems that this resource is working. The problem comes from folder and permisions that needs this configuration. The folders that I expose on path.repo doesn't exist, so it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the existing output using `YAML.load` like so:

```
require 'yaml'
=> true

config = 'path.repo:
 - "/backups/s3_currently_dev"
 - "/backups/s3_currently"
 - "/backups/s3_daily"
 - "/backups/s3_weekly"
 - "/backups/s3_monthly"'
=> "path.repo:\n- \"/backups/s3_currently_dev\"\n- \"/backups/s3_currently\"\n- \"/backups/s3_daily\"\n- \"/backups/s3_weekly\"\n- \"/backups/s3_monthly\""

doc = YAML.load config
=> {"path.repo"=>["/backups/s3_currently_dev", "/backups/s3_currently", "/backups/s3_daily", "/backups/s3_weekly", "/backups/s3_monthly"]}

doc["path.repo"]
=> ["/backups/s3_currently_dev", "/backups/s3_currently", "/backups/s3_daily", "/backups/s3_weekly", "/backups/s3_monthly"]
```